# How to determine the Google Analytics registered email address

Tags: html, google-analytics

Hi I am working in a project received from another company development team. They have set up the Google Analytic code. Now I want to check the traffic of the site. Unfortunately the team that developed the code is not available. I checked in the google forums also. Is there a way to find out the email that was registered with the analytic code? If so please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not available"? Is that currently not available, or no longer available? In the Google product forums, there is a sticky post (ie. permanent post) that tells you how to go about doing an account recovery. You will need an AdWords account though in order to speak to someone in person.

Comment: I was managed to get the credentials from previous development team and be able to use the Analytic data. As like you said to recover an account I should need AdWords account. At that time I don't have any account details, but only the Analytic code in the HTML page. Any way Thanks for your response.